# How to move c:\inetpub\temp\appPools to another disk?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have `Windows Server 2008 x64 SP2` installed on my server and `IIS 7.0`.

I have move successfully all other directories under `C:\inetpub\` folder.

But `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools` still exists and contains temporary files.

How to move it to another disk? I have searched registry and *.xml files in \system32 but didn't found it. Where can this settings be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ha-ha!

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WAS\Parameters /v ConfigIsolationPath /t REG_SZ /d E:\inetpub\temp\appPools
```

Comment: I tried doing this and I see the new item in my registry, but when I create app pools, I see folders for the new ones are still showing up on C, not in the D: folder that I set in the reg add command.